# How change from ForeignKey to ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to change one variable from ForeignKey to ManyToManyField. Obtained the following error when I try to do a command migrate:

"ValueError: Cannot alter field videos.Video.machine into videos.Video.machine - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)"

How can solve this problem?

Comment: You can add a m2m field, perform your custom migration and then in another migration delete the old one and possibly rename the new.

Answer (score 0):

There are really two ways to go here (that I can think of off top of my head):

1. Create a temporary field to store the current data of videos.Video.machine, remove videos.Video.machine field, add videos.Video.machine back as a m2m field, migrate the data from the temporary field into this new field, and remove the temporary field.
2. Create a new field, i.e. videos.Video.machines that is m2m, copy the current field videos.Video.machine into it, and then remove the videos.Video.machine field.

I would personally go with the second since it is not only easier but the naming makes more sense anyway!